# Adding the is_front variable to a Paragraphs template

Tags: theming, 8

Is the is_front variable not available in a Paragraphs template override?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          {% if is_front and content.field_section_title %}
            <h2>{{ content.field_section_title }}</h2>
          {% elseif content.field_section_title %}
            <h4>{{ content.field_section_title }}</h4>
          {% endif %}

          {{ content.field_text }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          {{ content.field_section_image }}
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

However, when I set a node that uses this paragraph type as the homepage, it doesn't take the is_front condition and just uses the h4 tag instead of the h2 which is what I would like for it to do.

Is there a way for my paragraphs templates to use the is_front condition? Or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add this with a preprocess function in `mytheme.theme` of your theme.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_paragraph().
 * @param $variables
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $variables['is_front'] = Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();

  // Ensure the cache varies correctly.
  // Drupal 8.2.x or lower
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';

  // Ensure the cache varies correctly.
  // Drupal 8.3.x+
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path.is_front'; 
}
```

This should add `is_front` as a variable to any paragraph twig template. Clear cache after adding this code.

Per 4k4's comment, if this is [Drupal 8.3 you will also need to add a cache context](https://www.drupal.org/node/2830442).

Comment: Excellent. This did the trick. Thanks again Kevin.

Comment: You also need a cache context `url.path`. In Drupal 8.3 there will be a new one for this: `url.path.is_front` - https://www.drupal.org/node/2830442

Comment: @Kevin, I've seen the edited answer about Drupal 8.3, you need the cache context for all D8 versions. Prior to 8.3 you don't have the front page specific one, so you can only use `'url.path'`.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer.

Comment: Great, that's a very nice answer!

Comment: I've added the updated code to my site and it crashes it. I get the following message: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "cache_context.url.path.is_front". Did you mean one of these: "cache_context.url.path", "cache_context.url.path.parent"? in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 157 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

Comment: That would only be if you are running Drupal 8.3.x , use the other if you are on 8.2 or lower.